# Can't set NSString property, crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My code:

```
     NSArray *keys = [piecesDict allKeys]; 
    //keys are NSStrings of sprite names, piecesDict is NSDictionary

    for(int i = 0; i < piecesDict.count; i++){
        PuzzlePiece *piece;
        id key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
        piece.keyName = key; }
```

The exact code that crashes is `piece.keyName = key`. I get  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. The `.keyName` property is `(nonatomic, retain)`. I have tried making `key` an `NSString *` or casting it with `(NSString *)key` to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you initialize `piece`?

Comment: If you're getting bad access on that assignment most likely "piece" is hosed, though it could also be that "key" is hosed.  Simplest thing is to NSLog both before the assignment and see which is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `piece`, you just declare a pointer and leave it hanging in the air. It will point to random crap and crash. You need to assign it to a proper instance:

```
PuzzlePiece *piece = [[PuzzlePiece alloc] init]; // or whatever
```

And seriously: **do learn C well** before attempting to make iOS apps or you will shoot yourself and your users in the foot.

Comment: Alright, I promise this is the worse I've ever been and will ever be. I'm refactoring code not writing it fresh, so I missed it.

Comment: @user339946 Sorry, I assumed you didn't know it was necessary.